# перекодировка 5 bit в 8 бит и обратно (mtk2)

Tags: перекодировка

Имеется двоичный файл, он создаётся из 5 битного потока (кодировка MTK2). Когда я читаю побайтно файл понимаю что 5 бит преобразуется в байт по какому-то закону, например: я знаю что сообщение начинается на ЗЦЗЦ пробел- в МТК2 это выглядит так (первый бит LSB):
10001 01110 10001 01110 00100, при побайтовом чтении с файла у меня получается 10000111 10010110 10000111 10010110 00100000 (тут MSB).
По какому алгоритму 5бит преобразуется в 8 бит?

Конечно можно составить словарь 8 битных символов, но тогда я могу только читать приходящие сообщения, а хотелось бы еще обратно преобразовывать 8 бит в 5 бит по тому же алгоритму.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%A2%D0%9A-2

Comment: Либо у вас попутаны 0/1 в вопросе, либо файл поломан - откуда вы его взяли?

Comment: Решено, в файле обычная кодировка cp866

Comment: Ха, я смотрел в КОИ.